# Use Boost.Python extension on hosting without libraries

Tags: c++, python-3.x, heroku, boost

I'm writing CPython extension that uses Boost.Python library. I want to use it on free web-hosting like Heroku or PythonAnywhere, where you can use only Python and pip packages.

Is it real to distribute CPython extension that uses Boost.Python with pip (and source files/shared libs)?

If so, can I use it on Heroku?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- we should have everything you need for boost pre-installed.

Comment: @GilesThomas I have tried it but this error: `ImportError: libboost_python-py35.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. On `Heroku` I can place requested lib in the project root and it will be found.

Comment: PythonAnywhere has libboost versions 1.55 and 1.54 installed for Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4.

Comment: @Glenn Yes it has, I have successfully build C++ code on PythonAnywhere with `setup.py` for Python34. But it's not cool that PythonAnywhere hasn't latest versions of Boost.Python...